# PHP Imap : Getting Unrepeated Subjects From Gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap, mail-server

I connect gmail and getting e-mails from gmail. When i use `imap_fetch_overwiev()`  method ; it reads all replies for the subject.

For Example :

RE : Hello Friend 
RE : Hello Friend 
RE : Hello Friend

How i block this ?

Comment: What do you expect?  Each reply is a message, and you asked for a message overview.

Comment: Hello Max (3)  3-> number of messages for example(GMAIL). But IMAP is return this value ;
RE: Hello Max
Re: Hello Max
Re: Hello Max